# Why do I keep getting "Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval"?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I keep running into this issue for the same reason, but none of the questions on SO seem to have the answer I keep needing, so I'm posting this question and answer just in case it helps someone else.

**Situation Setup**

I've gone ahead and loaded a csv file as a data.frame and cleaned it up with a bit of dplyr. Obviously using pipes `%>%` for brevity.

I set up the data file with some code along the lines of:

```
raw.data <- read_csv('myfile.csv')

cleaned.data <- raw.data %>%
  select(date, columns, I, care, about) %>%
  filter(columns == "criteria") %>%
  group_by(date, columns) %>%
  summarize(analysis.value = statistic())
```

Now, I'm all ready to create a graph of `analysis.value` against `date` and `columns`, so I switch gears and get ready to use ggplot. My code looks something like this:

```
cleaned.data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date)) %>%
  geom_line(aes(y = analysis.value, col = columns))
```

...which I'm expecting to generate a line plot with `date` on the x axis, `analysis.value` on the y axis, and separate colored lines based on `columns`.

However, instead I just keep getting this message:

```
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval
```

**And no matter what I do I just keep getting this same message**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that when I haven't set up a ggplot function in a while I always, **always**, ***always***...forget that ggplot doesn't use the `%>%` pipe characters to chain functions!

Instead of `%>%` I should be putting `+` between my ggplot functions.

To summarize:

**BAD**

```
cleaned.data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date)) %>%
  geom_line(aes(y = analysis.value, col = columns))
```

**GOOD**

```
cleaned.data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = analysis.value, col = columns))
```

I always wind up searching SO frantically for about 20 minutes only to eventually realize that I've made the same mistake **again**.